# Can we define procedure or select statement on more than one database?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need some data of one db and some data of another db and perform some operation. Can we do this in sql server 2008? In my project suppose I want to fetch data of doctor and Chemist database in CRM Database and want to generate operation, How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If both db belongs on the same sql server instance you can use full qualified names of objects like `[DbName].[scheme].[table]` if on different instances then you must create linked server. Of course, providing access as expected.